# How can one client check if another client is connected to the broker in python.?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

Let's say I have two clients with client id's `device1` and `device2`. Before `device1` sends a publish message to broker it needs to check if `device2` is still connected to the broker. How can I check the connectivity of `device2` from client `device1`.?

I am using `mosquitto broker` and `paho client`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you can not do this at the MQTT protocol level.

The best you can do is use a status topic. When a client connects it publishes a retained message with payload `true` to a topic like `status/[client-id]`. Just before it disconnects is publishes a message with the payload `false` to the same topic. To ensure it's marked as away if it crashes then you need to set a Last Will and Testament message to publish `false` when the broker notices the client is no longer responding to pings.

Comment: Would be great to see a working example of this

Comment: Maybe http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/checking-active-mqtt-client-connections/ is close enough